# find posts that don't have a custom taxonomy

Tags: wp-query, custom-taxonomy

I am using a custom taxonomy series to keep track of posts that are in a series.  I would like to find the posts that do not have a series.  I have the following query:

```
global $wpdb;
$pr = $wpdb->prefix;    

$sql_no_series=
    "Select  
            *
    from    
            wp_term_taxonomy tt,
            wp_term_relationships tr,
            wp_posts p 
    WHERE   
            tt.term_taxonomy_id=tr.term_taxonomy_id AND
            tr.object_id=p.ID AND
            p.ID NOT IN 
                (Select  
                        p.ID
                from    
                        wp_term_taxonomy tt,
                        wp_term_relationships tr,
                        wp_posts p 
                WHERE   
                        tt.term_taxonomy_id=tr.term_taxonomy_id AND
                        tr.object_id=p.ID AND
                        tt.taxonomy='series')
    AND tt.term_taxonomy_id = $category ";

$no_series = $wpdb->get_results($sql_no_series,ARRAY_A);
```

Is there a way to do it using WP_Query?

Answer (score 3):

Emily's answer is mostly correct, just that the operator shouldn't have an underscore in it:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'my_post_type',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'series',
            'operator' => 'NOT EXISTS',
        ),
    ),
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work, where series is the taxonomy name and not a option within a taxonomy:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'my_post_type',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'series',
            'operator' => 'NOT_EXISTS',
        ),
    ),
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

reference with plenty of code examples: https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters

Comment: doesn't seem to be working...

Comment: Did you update 'my_post_type' to the post type you're looking at? Also can you confirm the taxonomy is 'series'. You may need to include the taxonomy terms and/or use a different operator (examples are in the link)

Comment: It's giving me all the posts whether or not it has a series.  I don't want to include the terms, because I want anything that has no series at all, even if I don't specify it.